# Assembler habits for knowing multiple assembler syntaxes?

Tags: assembly

I have programmed and RCE'd using Intel assembler for the past 5 years (both x86, x64).  It is all that I know and love (when it comes to assembler languages).

However, it is incredibly confusing for me when I have to code in AT&T syntax or use a different architecture which is weird compared to Intel standing (such as the MIPS instruction set).

What can I do to break these habits and help me get used to programming on more than one instruction set?

Comment: I though there is no Intel "assembler" anymore. Where I can get one?

Comment: @johnfound: It's the syntax style, not the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What usually helps me is to think about them as entirely different languages.

Imagine knowing Python and C++ and then learning Haskell. You'll end up developing a somewhat different style for each different language.

Well, treat the different assembly instruction sets the same way. Imagine they are entirely different languages.

As for the AT&T syntax...uhhh...can't help you there. :)